# decimaljs add method work incorrectly for big number

Tags: javascript, decimal, decimal.js

I'm using the Add method of decimalJS v10.4.3 to add 2 numbers: `12345678907812569090001` and `5001`.

The result should be `12345678907812569095002` but decimalJS returns `12345678907812569095000`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be because precision is less than the number of digits, so it ends with `...00`

```js
var a = new Decimal("12345678907812569090001")
var b = new Decimal("5001")
var c = a.add(b)
console.log (c.toFixed())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/9.0.0/decimal.min.js" integrity="sha512-zPQm8HS4Phjo9pUbbk+HPH3rSWu5H03NFvBpPf6D9EU2xasj0ZxhYAc/lvv/HVDWMSE1Autj19i6nZOfiVQbFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

However should we set precision to a large enough number, it works:
default is `Decimal.precision = 20`

```js
Decimal.precision = 100

var a = new Decimal("12345678907812569090001")
var b = new Decimal("5001")
var c = a.add(b)
console.log(c.toFixed())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/9.0.0/decimal.min.js" integrity="sha512-zPQm8HS4Phjo9pUbbk+HPH3rSWu5H03NFvBpPf6D9EU2xasj0ZxhYAc/lvv/HVDWMSE1Autj19i6nZOfiVQbFQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```